# Whatsapp API not Working On desktop and PHP page

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

Good Day

I had a Whatsapp API I used in a URL to send a Whatsapp to a specific person or group in my contact list. Below is the code I used.

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/resolve?deeplink=/%3Ftext%3D%252AeTrack%2BNational%2BLookout%253A%252A
```

It normally worked fine and no issues. Now looks like Whatsapp page has been removed. I need a similar external link to send messages from my PHP page to a whatsapp contact or group. We use either Whatsapp Web or their Downloaded app on Windows. On our Android phones the link still works and opens Whatsapp and we can select the recipient. But using Chrome and a Windows system it does not open Whatsapp anymore.